# If $x_n = \cos{\sqrt{n + 1}} - \cos{\sqrt{n}}$, what is $\lim_{x \to \infty} x_n$?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

If $x_n = \cos{\sqrt{n + 1}} - \cos{\sqrt{n}}$, what is $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$?

I think it may be $0$, because $\sqrt{n + 1}$ and $\sqrt{n}$ are two very close angles. But I don't know how to prove it. If I use the formula for $\cos - \cos$, I get $-0 \cdot \infty$.

Can you help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: Difference to product formula. Also, it should be $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n$, not $x\to \infty$.

Comment: @xbh, sorry it was a typo.

Comment: You are right to think that $\sqrt{n + 1}$ and $\sqrt{n}$ being close together (for large $n$) is a sufficient condition, because it is true that $\lvert\cos\theta - \cos\phi\rvert \leqslant \lvert\theta - \phi\rvert$ for all $\theta, \phi$. One can prove this in various ways, but it is geometrically obvious from the fact that $\lvert\theta - \phi\rvert$ is the length of a path on the unit circle starting from $P = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ and ending at $Q = (\cos\phi, \sin\phi)$, and $\lvert\cos\theta - \cos\phi\rvert$ is the length of the projection on the $x$-axis of the line segment $PQ$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well $$\cos{\sqrt{n + 1}} - \cos{\sqrt{n}}=2\sin\frac12(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n)\color{red}{\sin\frac12(\sqrt n-\sqrt{n+1})}$$ and as $n\to\infty$ the term in red goes to zero.

Comment: Yes, but how do you prove that $\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n+1}$ tends to $0$? If you write it as $\sqrt{n+1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}} - 1\right)$, you get $\infty \cdot 0$.

Comment: It is a non-determination case... I don't know how is it called in English.

Comment: @IulianOleniuc Rationalize the numerator,  then you would see.

Comment: @xbh, thank you :) I got it!

Answer (score 2):

$$|\cos x-\cos y|\le|x-y|$$
(consider the points $(\cos x,\sin x)$ and $(\cos y,\sin y)$ on the unit circle).
Therefore
$$|x_n|\le\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}\to0.$$

Comment: Lord.$|\cos x-\cos y| \le |x-y|$.Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

$f(n)=\dfrac{\cos \sqrt{n+1}-\cos √n}{1}=$

$\sin (√t) \cdot (1/2)t^{-1/2}$, where $t \in (n,n+1)$.

$n \rightarrow \infty $  implies $t \rightarrow \infty$.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(n)=$

$ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} (1/2)( \sin √t) t^{-1/2}=0.$

Used : MVT