# Show that $|b-a|\geq|\cos a-\cos b|$ for all real numbers $\,a\,$ and $\,b$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, absolute-value

$\mathbf{Question:}$ Show that $|b-a|\geq|\cos a-\cos b|$ for all real numbers a and b.

$\mathbf{My\ attempt:}$

The Mean Value Theorem states that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ then there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=\frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$

Using the MVT where $f(c)=\cos c:$

$$
f'(c)=\frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
$$

$$
f'(c)(b-a)=f(b)-f(a)
$$

$$
(-\sin c)(b-a)=\cos(b)-\cos(a)
$$

$$
(\sin c)(b-a)=\cos(a)-\cos(b)
$$

Taking the absolute value of both sides:

$$
|\sin c||b-a|= |\cos(a)-\cos(b)|
$$

Because $|\sin c |\leq 1,\,$ we can bound $|\sin c|$ by $1$
$$
1 \cdot|b-a| \geq |\cos(a)-\cos(b)|
$$

Thus $|b-a|\geq|\cos a-\cos b|$ for all real numbers $a$ and $b$

Comment: Your proof is perfect when $a \neq b$.

Comment: Well the first line considers $\cos$ over $(a,b)$ for differentiability so I would not make a point on this trivial case here @Gribouillis

Comment: @nicomezi The question says "show that", I take it for granted that one cannot ignore silently trivial cases.

Comment: Proof is fine. You can presume that $a \neq b$ as if $a=b$ the inequality is vacuous. Some instructors nitpick pointlessly.

Comment: If there were multiple trivial cases and if we were not dealing with elementary real analysis, I would agree. I consent that the most rigorous proof would have been to treat it as well however. But being picky over this particular point here seems pointless to me.

Comment: @copper.hat You would be surprised to see how often students forget special cases in their proofs and don't even realize it.

Comment: Commonly for derivable functions you always get Lipschitz inequality $|f(x)-f(y)|\le||f'||_\infty|x-y|$. This is the case here with $||\sin||_\infty=1$.

Comment: To explain further on zwim's comment, the inequality is proven exactly like you did. And often we take this more general form as granted.

Comment: @Gribouillis: It is not confined to students, the development of proofs is a social process, and authors rarely get them right first time. It is misleading and frankly a little discouraging to suggest otherwise to students. I like Keynes line "It is better to be roughly right than precisely wrong."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even faster you can use fundamental theorem of calculus and assuming for example $a≤b$
$$
\begin{align*}
|\cos(a)-\cos(b)| &= \left|\int_a^b \sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right| ≤ \int_a^b \left|\sin(x)\right|\mathrm{d}x
\\
&≤ \int_a^b 1\,\mathrm{d}x = |b-a|
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: You should add the substitution $a=c+\frac{\pi}{2}$$\quad$$b=d+\frac{\pi}{2}$ to get the correct result .

Comment: Oh I didn't see it was asked for cosine, I changed sine by cosine.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $$cos(A)-cos(B)=2sin(\frac{A+B}{2})sin(\frac{B-A}{2})$$
$$ x \geq \sin(x) ; x\geq0 \Rightarrow |x|\geq |\sin(x)|$$
$$\sin(x)\leq1 $$
 For $x \neq 0$ $$|\frac{x}{\sin(x)}|\geq 1$$

Let $\frac{b-a}{2}=x$

$$|\frac{\frac{b-a}{2}}{\sin(\frac{b-a}{2})}|\geq 1$$

$$|\frac{\frac{b-a}{2}}{\sin(\frac{b-a}{2})}|\geq \sin(\frac{a+b}{2}) $$

After some rearranging,

$$|b-a|\geq|2\sin(\frac{b-a}{2})\sin(\frac{a+b}{2})|$$

$$ |b-a| \geq |cos(a)-cos(b)|$$
For a=b case, x=0 and that becomes a limit in this case $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{\sin(x)}=1$ which is true in this expression since $\sin(\frac{a+b}{2})$ is bounded;

$$|\frac{\frac{b-a}{2}}{\sin(\frac{b-a}{2})}|\geq \sin(\frac{a+b}{2})$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B$ be two points on the unit circle with coordinates $$A=(x_1,y_1),B=(x_2,y_2).$$ Then $$|x_1-x_2|\leq d(A,B)\leq {\rm length~of~arc~joining~}A{\rm~and~}B,$$ where $d(A,B)$ is the length of cord $AB$. Note that angle is just a way of measuring arc length on the unit circle.

Comment: Related: [If $x_n = \cos{\sqrt{n + 1}} - \cos{\sqrt{n}}$, what is $\lim_{x \to \infty} x_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948956/if-x-n-cos-sqrtn-1-cos-sqrtn-what-is-lim-x-to-infty-x-n).